# Notification bar intermittently displays a blank space

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, answers, notification-bar

I came across this bug a few weeks ago using Firefox 3.6: sometimes, when a notification should appear, the space for the bar is carved out at the top of the screen but doesn't get filled with anything.  I couldn't repro it, and it eventually stopped happening, so I chalked it up to random inexplicable weirdness and let it go.  Then, yesterday, using Chrome 5.0, I saw this in the middle of editing a question (freehand circle/text added after the fact, of course):

[image: Notification bar is blank]

Has anyone else encountered this blank notification message behavior?  I still can't figure out how to repro it, so I need some help figuring out what's going on.

<sub>(I would also accept "'We are aware of this issue and are actively working on a fix.' -Valued Associate ♦.")</sub>

> Awareness bump for tangentially related bug: at the time, I barely noticed the notification area — the white just blends in — and figured it was probably a new answer that wouldn't interfere with my edit.  Afterwards, I found out that some comment magic happens automatically with question closures, and I ran into [a known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/closing-as-exact-duplicate-missing-links-to-the-duplicate-questions); credit to Lance's comment on the [original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57678/i-dont-want-to-be-listed-in-google-search-results).

Comment: I get this if I end up in the edit window long enough to get a report that I'm going to trample someone's edit. However, it's only happened twice and I'm still navigating with a badge reward banner so it might be because I have too many concurrent banners. Also, that latter point isn't a "bug", it's expected behavior in edit trampling.

Comment: You should use IE ... F_CK, what am I writing? - Nice circle btw.

Comment: @Ladybug, I'm going to go ahead and pretend that didn't happen.  __And don't let it happen again.__

Comment: +1, I was just about to post this bug I couldn't find it by searching.  @Pop: come IE9, *"You should use IE"* might not universally translate into *"Please slap me in the face"*.

Comment: @Andy, I will hide behind my timestamp.

Comment: Quick, someone change their name to Valued Associate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a javascript bug that was fixed a week or so ago - let us know if it still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I've had it happen in IE8 when I get a notification that there's a new answer in the post I'm writing my own answer to, click to load the new answer, and then get a *second* notification about even more new answers - it's just a blank space on the second go.

Comment: Yes, it always happens if you get a second notification (at least in my experience)

Comment: Sorry to make things difficult, but I've gotten two notifications with no errors before.

Comment: I can confirm that this only happens on the second notification after the first one has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen as well, but always figured it was an AJAX timeout on my (sometimes) slow home network connection.   Using Mac OS X/Safari.

Comment: FWIW, whenever I encounter this bug, I'm on a fast corporate connection.  I don't see it at home, but I also use SE sites less at home.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it a few times in some of my browsers. I usually just refresh the page (unless I'm editing) because the bar just stays up there.

I'm surprised that there is no error checking when doing AJAX calls for updates. It looks like the AJAX call returned a blank or incomplete page and the code just stuck it in the bar div without verifying everything was there.

Need moar error checking