# Message is not displayed, but the message area is!

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification bar intermittently displays a blank space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57764/notification-bar-intermittently-displays-a-blank-space)

it's not the first time, but this time I did a simple screencast

> http://bit.ly/dAt8fY

the message are is there, but there is no message at all, even after refreshing the page.

[image]

Comment: It's a different page, but this looks to most likely be the [same issue as here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57764/notification-bar-intermittently-displays-a-blank-space).

Comment: Yes, same behavior alright, though it was the first time I access it and I was not editing it as the 2 votes answer suggests it can be happen... :-/

Comment: Mark duplicate?