# Edit notification display issue

Tags: bug

I just noticed a toolbar notification which pops up when editing a question, telling me that someone else has edited it and if my changes are to be committed, they need to be more detailed than the previous edit.

I clicked to close the notification and was left with a blank bar at the top of the screen:

[image: Screenshot]

Is this intentional? Would it not be better to put a fixed toolbar over the top of the profile so we don't get a blank space?

Comment: Need more freehand circles!

Comment: @hjpotter92 Unfortunately the freehand circles made it look even more confusing. Added dodgy arrow and self-explanatory text instead

Comment: problem with browser!

Comment: You're not sitting on a Beta/Nightly build of Chrome/Chromium, right?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Comment: [The return of the bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57764/152859).