# Use most-selected duplicate as the first duplicate shown in the banner

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When a question is closed as a duplicate, it appears that the choices for the duplicate question links are presented in one of three orders<sup>1</sup>:

1. Most answers
2. First duplicate chosen
3. Undefined

Any of these are not ideal, as when someone [fat fingers a duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114342/embedding-a-scripting-language-into-my-application), it ends up in the header of the question. Normally this would not be bothersome, except when the fat fingered target was first or had the most answers (I don't know and could not find the [sort order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab) [in my search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22063/should-users-be-allowed-to-remove-the-possible-duplicate-links-on-closed-quest) [of related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103489/closed-as-exact-duplicate-banner-should-link-more-clearly-to-the-exact-duplica)).

[image: I seriously hope no more than one person selected this duplicate]

Instead, I propose that the links to the duplicate questions be ordered based on:

1. Number of users who selected a given duplicate
2. Number of answers for the given duplicate
3. (*optional*) Total question score of the given duplicate

This order is better<sup>2</sup> as it would minimize the pain cause by fat fingers, and maximize the position of "more selected" duplicates (assuming of course that a majority of close votes were not the result of fat fingers).

<sub>1. This is a guess.

2. For some definition of *better*.</sub>

Comment: Does order actually matter? There can be *at most* five. That's not a lot of clicking for answer-seekers to have to do.

Comment: @user414076: if four folks chose one dupe target and one person chose the other, it would make sense to provide the more popular target first. Duplicate targets are supposed to be useful, so providing a helpful order for answer-seekers...well it is helpful.