# Why can we delete the duplicate link?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

For example [this question on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125158/155556) was [**closed**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/125158/revisions) as a duplicate.

The OP, in his infinite wisdom, ***edited out*** the duplicate link!

> And then someone flagged it for moderator attention, and a moderator rolled it back and locked it with a warning to the OP. This is the way in which such things are handled...
>
> --Shog9

Why is this allowed?

This should be prevented, or the duplicate question link should be present in the close reason.

Now if any future users (who are not used to the Stack Exchange) come, they will see that the question is **closed** due to it being a **duplicate** but they will not know *what* the duplicate link is.

I propose that we put a **non-editable** header at the top of duplicate questions that the OP **cannot** remove, unless the question is reopened.

---

Related:

- [Add link to duplicate question in "closed as exact duplicate" message box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99503/155556)

Comment: I agree - but it can be useful to have that text in the body so you can either a) add more possible duplicates or b) update the link if the original master gets deleted for some reason.

Comment: @ChrisF maybe make it so it is only editable by closers and mods (or even 10k users).

Comment: @ChrisF hehe now I need a new example because the question was reopened....

Comment: Do you think that anything has changed since the old discussion in '09 that would warrant a new question?

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_ Yes I do, since all of the new updates happened.

Comment: Meh, http://i.stack.imgur.com/HLXU0.png gets my vote.

Comment: If you haven't already, roll-back the change.

Comment: Of course you realize, I *had* to close this as a duplicate. And now, you must edit out the link - for *maximum irony*

Comment: @Shog9 oh, but of course. ^_^

Comment: @Shog9 I also updated the links in the OP.

Comment: Did you just...oh boy.

Answer (score 4):

It is editable because it's an easy and flexible solution. If you have special restrictions for the duplicate section you have to make sure they are enforced and have to manage permissions and a user interface for those who actually *can* edit that part.

You add this complexity for not much gain. There seem to be not many problems with this currently and in the rare case where someone *insists* on messing with the duplicate section in an inappropriate way, a moderator can just lock the post to stop that.

Comment: This, once again, makes me think of [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles/44113#44113) - "*How is this any different than posting a bunch of unicode spaces in the post body? Or other general abuse of the system?  The short answer is "don't do that", and the longer answer is "if you keep doing that, there will be consequences."*"