# Make "Possible Duplicate" editable

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, flags

Every now and then, after reading a new question and marking it as a *possible duplicate*, I end up finding a **better candidate** for *possible duplicate*.

Unfortunately, I can't EDIT my vote and update the link of the *possible duplicate* to point to a better match.

I think it would be great if we could do that.

Comment: One more reason to really think about this feature-request.

Comment: If you *really really* have found a better candidate, flag as other and include *as much detail as possible* about what you're trying to do.  Notice how I emphasized *as much detail as possible*.  Anything less and we'll probably skip over the flag.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but that's a lot of effort to fix something so simple. There has to be a simpler way to do it. I don't think this feature-request can be that hard to implement.

Answer (score -2):

**After** it is closed you can click the edit button::

[image: edit button]

So when it is closed as duplicate, you can **add** the question you think is a duplicate as well!

Example where someone edited and added thier own link: [Why can we delete the duplicate link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125158/155556)

---

At the moment there is **no way** to change what you think the question is a duplicate of once you have voted to close.

Comment: This is only true **post** closure. The OP is looking for a solution **pre** closure.

Comment: @ChrisF I (ninja) edited my answer.